# Formulário enviando email e saindo da sessão

Tags: html, laravel

Criei um formulário com laravel. O meu site e onepage porem quando envio meu formulário a pagina volta para sessao home eu gostaria que ela fica-se na sessão de contato isso é possível?

Segue meu código:

O html:

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif

                @if (session('message'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {!! session('message')  !!}
                    </div>
                @endif
                {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'FormController@postContato', 'role' => 'form', 'class'=>'form-block contact')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('nome', null, array('placeholder'=>'Digite nome', 'class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('email', null, array('placeholder'=>'Digite e-mail', 'class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('telefone', null, array('placeholder'=>'Digite seu Telefone', 'class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('mensagem', null, array('placeholder'=>'Mensagem', 'class'=>'form-control', 'rows'=>'5')) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Enviar Mensagem', array('class' => 'btn-black btn-blue bounce-green send'), array('id' => 'btn_submit')) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/', 'FormController@postContato');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Requests;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('/');
    }

    public function postContato(Request $request) {
        $rules = array( 'nome' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email', 'telefone' => 'required', 'mensagem' => 'required' );
        $errors = [
            'required'    => 'O campo :attribute é obrigatório.',
            'email'    => 'Digite um email válido.',
        ];
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $errors);
        $data = array();
        $data['nome'] = $request->input("nome");
        $data['email'] = $request->input("email");
        $data['telefone'] = $request->input("telefone");
        $data['mensagem'] = $request->input("mensagem");


        if($validation->passes()) {
            /*Mail::send('emails.contato', $data, function($message) {
                $message->from($request->input("email"), $request->input("nome"));
                $message->to('felipe@agenciafront.com.br') ->subject('TorreForte');
            });*/
            return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
        }
        return redirect('/')->withErrors($validation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente as quando se usa onepage layout as paginas/seções são identificadas pela hashtag #, exemplo, `#pagina1` `#pagina2`, então na sua URL que retorna para o form adiciona o "link" da seção.

```
if($validation->passes()) {
    /*Mail::send('emails.contato', $data, function($message) {
        $message->from($request->input("email"), $request->input("nome"));
        $message->to('felipe@agenciafront.com.br') ->subject('TorreForte');
    });*/
    //note que troquei de / para /#contato
    return redirect('/#contato')->with('message', 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
}
//note que troquei de / para /#contato
return redirect('/#contato')->withErrors($validation);
```

Comment: nesse caso por exemplo no html fica so um id="contact" né

Comment: Creio que sim, no site que estou desenvolvendo agora faço exatamente isso, na seção de contato é assim: `<section id="contato" class="">...</div>` e o link para ela no menu é `#contato`

Comment: deu certo cara e nois sauhsuahsua